# Is there a function in R that allows you to specify print out positions like SAS can do?

Tags: r, sas

Like in SAS I can do

```
put @5 value1
    @12 "="
    @24 estimate1
;
```

Is there something I can do in R with functions like "cat" to print out positioned values and objects?

Let me know if my question is clear to you.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't that just put those characters in the log file? Do you want to customize the console output, or make custom table latex code, or write customized output to a file? Something else?

Comment: Yes,I want to write customized output in txt file, where I can,say ,write a letter at 10th character space in a line, how can I do this?

Comment: You need to show us what the output from SAS looks like in this case, otherwise we are guessing. Does "@12" mean column 12, or after another 12 spaces, or with a width of 12 spaces? What happens if you print something that has more characters than the space you want it to go in? ANd so on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a guess. This creates a long empty string and then puts values in it via substr:

```
fixput <- function(...,nchar=80){    
  s=paste0(rep(" ",nchar),collapse="")
  args=list(...)
  for(arg in seq(1,length(args),by=2)){
    substr(s,args[arg],nchar)=as.character(args[arg+1])
  }
  s    
}
```

Usage:

```
> value1=1.234
> estimate1=pi
> fixput(5, value1, 12, "=", 24, estimate1)
[1] "    1.234  =           3.14159265358979                                         "
```

Note it returns a string so if you want it output in a script you can just `cat` it. Also note what happens if the interpolated values are long:

```
> value1=pi
> fixput(5, value1, 12, "=", 24, estimate1)
[1] "    3.14159=65358979   3.14159265358979                                         "
```

Comment: Exactly what I want, and I must say "How can u make it this elegant!"

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf()` is your friend - to quote from the help page

> A wrapper for the C function sprintf, that returns a character vector containing a formatted combination of text and variable values.

Refer to the examples in the help page `?sprintf`, e.g.

```
sprintf("min 10-char string '%10s'", c("a", "ABC", "and an even longer one"))
```

Will produce:

```
[1] "min 10-char string '         a'"            
[2] "min 10-char string '       ABC'"            
[3] "min 10-char string 'and an even longer one'"
```

While the following working on real numbers

```
n <- 1:8
sprintf(paste0("e with %2d digits = %.", n, "g"), n, exp(1))
```

produces:

```
 [1] "e with  1 digits = 3"                  
 [2] "e with  2 digits = 2.7"                
 [3] "e with  3 digits = 2.72"               
 [4] "e with  4 digits = 2.718"              
 [5] "e with  5 digits = 2.7183"             
 [6] "e with  6 digits = 2.71828"            
 [7] "e with  7 digits = 2.718282"           
 [8] "e with  8 digits = 2.7182818"
```

Comment: That produces outputs of a given length, I think the OP wants things at a given character position.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way of doing that in R, but one can build it up using sprintf() or in your function.  Perl has the notion of templates.

Comment: Spacedman got it, thanks Sean as well, I am sure we could build a function using sprintf() to achieve it, I will dig into it.